# Get the properties of a JSON that are not empty

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a function in Typescript in which I obtain all the values referring to a data in JSON format, some of the JSON fields are empty. How could you get that data?

This is my function:

```
let datosCod;
    for (let get in Object.keys(transfConsData)) {
      const value = transfConsData[get];
      if (value.Country === 'Colombia') {
        datosCod = value;
      }
    }
```

This is what the variable `dataCod` returns:

```
{ Country: 'Colombia',
  Ser: '',
  Ins: 'blue',
  BBDD: ''}
```

This is the information I want to obtain:

```
{ Country: 'Colombia',
  Ins: 'blue'}

totalValues = 2
```

Comment: The main issue is using `in` instead of `of` in your `for` loop

Comment: @Evert I have tried both ways and I receive the same object using of or in in the variable ``datosCod``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const data = { Country: "Colombia", Ser: "", Ins: "blue", BBDD: "" };
const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).filter(([_, v]) => !!v)
);

console.log(filteredData);
// output: Object { Country: "Colombia", Ins: "blue" }
```

The key element is filtering the data. You see `.filter(([_, v]) => !!v)` block filters out *any falsy values that means `null` and other falsy values including empty string will also be gone.* If you want to filter ONLY empty strings, you may replace this `.filter(([_, v]) => !!v)` with `.filter(([_, v]) => v !== '')`. But I guess you wanted to weed out all values which are falsy.

Without `fromEntries` using `reduce`

```js
const data = { Country: "Colombia", Ser: "", Ins: "blue", BBDD: "" };
const filteredData = Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([_, v]) => !!v)
  .reduce((cum, [k, v]) => {
    cum[k] = v;
    return cum;
  }, {});

console.log(filteredData);
// output: Object { Country: "Colombia", Ins: "blue" }
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it without using the ``fromEntries`` property? I am working with es6 in the whole project and changing it to es2019 would give a lot of problems

Comment: Ok ok, now it returns the correct data, but how can I get the total data from this new object? I am having trouble iterating over ``filteredData``

Comment: You wanted to get the total number of entries? You can just do `Object.keys(filteredData).length`, no?

Comment: No, because I need to go through it to get the total data without counting the Country property, that is, in this example the total will be 1 (Ins: 'blue')

Comment: Ok I put a -1 because it will always be a field that I have to remove and that's it, thanks

Comment: Another problem: I am using the same function in another method to obtain the data from another JSON, the cum variable returns the following error: ```The element has an "any" type implicitly because the expression of type "string" cannot be use to index the type "{}".
   No index signature was found with a parameter of type "string" in type "{}".``` Why is this?